# How to disable a link using CSS?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have the following link in a `wordpress` page.

This class is a link. Is it possible to disable the link using only `CSS`?

```
<a class="select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl"><i class="material-icons select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationIcon___3WFzp">timelapse</i><span class="select-slot__serviceName___14MHL">Employee Assistance Line</span></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
.select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl {
  pointer-events: none;
  color: black; (the color which is your normal text maybe?)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointer-event:none;`.

```css
.select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl{
  pointer-event:none;
}
```

```html
<a class="select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl"><i class="material-icons select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationIcon___3WFzp">timelapse</i><span class="select-slot__serviceName___14MHL">Employee Assistance Line</span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl
{
pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Add this to css.

If you want to show the link as a normal text use this.

```
 .select-slot__serviceStaffOrLocationButton___5GUjl
{
pointer-events: none; 
cursor: default; 
text-decoration: none; 
color: black; 
}
```